# Is DevDefined.OAuth Compatible with Xamarin Cross-Platform Projects

Tags: c#, oauth, xamarin, mvvmcross

Is it possible to use the library `DevDefined.OAuth` in a Xamarin Cross-Platform project?

There isn't much if any articles, tutorials or posts about using this in Xamarin. I am specifically using it in a MVVM Cross PCL project (so I have a core, Android and iOS project). I dont want to implement a solution only to find it wont work on a iOS or Android or Windows Phone. I've already run into this with Xamarin.Auth (cant be used in PCL's) and other libraries.

This [post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18452/devdefined-oauth-throws-error-in-mvvm-ios-xamarin-project) about it not working in a Xamarin.iOS project irks me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in that post you are referencing appears to be that they didn't add

```
using System.Linq;
```

I have had this issue in Xamarin Studio where I need to explicitly add the using myself.

As for the library you are asking about we need more information on how it is constructed.  Is it a NuGet package that has references solely for PCL?  Does it have references for iOS, Android and Windows?  If it is a PCL package that is compatible with profile 259 then it should work fine.